# ReferenceError: ProductStore is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to migrate some old javascript / backbone code over to our new system and I'm running into the following error.

```
ReferenceError: ProductStore is not defined 
ProductStore.Options = {},

ReferenceError: ProductStore is not defined 
ProductStore.type= "board";
```

My JS file looks like this.

```
ProductStore.Options= {},
    function() {
        "use strict", ProductStore.Options.Product = Backbone.Model.extend({ 
             //do something
         })
    }(),
    function() {
        "use strict", ProductStore.Options.ProductView = Backbone.View.extend({
             //do something
        })
    }()
```

There is no other js files, so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Error says it all, you can't say:

`ProductStore.options = {}`

unless you have already declared `ProductStore` (and defined it to be an object).

e.g.

```
var ProductStore = {};
```

Comment: So I altered the code ProductStore = {}; function() { and now I'm seeing the following error SyntaxError: function statement requires a name

Comment: I'm assuming I need to declare my ProductStore object in the beginning of my js file like so var ProductStore = {};
    function() {
        "use strict", ProductStore .Options.Product = Backbone.Model.extend({  After completing that, I'm getting the following SyntaxError: function statement requires a name
 

function() {

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a ProductStore JS object first:

```
var ProductStore = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your `,` with `;`

```
var ProductStore = {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but best practice is to declare object is to make it fail safe. Someone told me the same in one of my project.

```
var ProductStore = ProductStore || {};
```

Comment: let me put together things that may help you to resolve your issues - http://jsfiddle.net/ylokesh/a7ha9sjj/1/

Comment: This is not "best practice" if you're the owner of `ProductStore` and you know you're defining it for the first time.

Comment: @Adam - Yes, you are right. But, what if this namespace is used across different JS files to map different functionalities for product store.